# Vector Bundle definition compared to direct product

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, symplectic-geometry, lie-derivative

I read that the simplest vector bundle is $E = M \times V$ where $M$ is a manifold and $V$ is some $r$-dimensional vector space. I suppose my confusion is with notation. My understanding is that if I say $A \times B$ it means pairs of elements $(a,b)$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, but a vector bundle means for each point we have an entire space of vectors...which is not the same as one point paired with one vector. So how come they can write $E=M \times V$?

Comment: No, a vector bundle comes equipped with a map from the total space $\pi: E=M\times V \to M$ to its base space, such that each fiber has a vector space structure which varies continuously. Here $\pi^{-1}(m) = \{m\}\times V$ which certianly has a vector space structure through $(m,v)+(m,v')=(m,v+v')$.

Comment: You are confused about set notation. For each $p\in M$ you have $\{p\}\times V$, so there's your vector space for each point of $M$.